# How to connect to MongoDB Atlas using Robo 3T?

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, robo3t

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB Atlas using Robo 3T.
I must be doing something wrong, cause when i'm trying to connect I get the following error message:
Failed to connect to cluster via SSL tunnel. 
in details: Error: ssl connection failure: Authentication failed.

What iv'e tried so far:

Selected a "Direct connection" type.
I used my primary cluster as address (including the port number)
for Authentication I used "admin" Database, and put my username (my email) and the password of MongoDB Atlas.
I also white listed my IP address, and even set it as "allow access from anywhere", though it's not secure.
I checked "Use self-signed certificate"
Nothing I do seems to work.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

At Atlas connections are SSL encrypted.

1. Go to SSL Tab in the connection settings window
2. Select `Use SSL Protocol` option
3. Now try connecting.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mani,
Unfortunately this does not work (I tried that with self-signed certificate)

Answer (score 0):

Exclude the port number in your cluster URI. :PORT. Exclude the port then use ssl and self certificate.